# Get system to accept fingerprint OR password

Tags: login, password, fingerprint-reader, pam

I have a working fingerprint scanner, but this does not allow me to unlock the login key ring. Therefor, I am looking for solutions to allow me to type my password to login whenever the key ring would be locked (after reboot or logout).

One solution that I know is possible is to edit files located in `/etc/pam.d` as described in [UNIX StackExchange question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/671075/use-fingerprint-reader-for-everything-but-first-login?newreg=40f76f25c77843588c85a5b105eca4fa), however I am not savvy enough to follow this solution in its entirety as I am not sure which files I would need to edit in `/etc/pam.d`, I have multiple files with gdm in the name and I do not know which ones are invoked upon initial logins or times when the login key ring would be locked.

A second solution that would be nice in general, but I do not know if it is possible to have my system look for and accept whatever it gets first: a password or a fingeprint as on iOS and Android. Currently, I would have to wait 10 seconds for the fingerprint to timeout. Basically, is there a way for pam modules to work simultaneously? This would be convenient in other situations, such as when I have my laptop lid closed or don't want to move my hand from the keyboard.

Thank you in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

At this moment the only way to achieve desired behavior is to use this awesome pam module: https://gitlab.com/mishakmak/pam-fprint-grosshack
It's awesome, because it provides good user experience that PAM project refuses to address for ages now.